# Compiling libnice for Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, stun, turn, libnice

I'm trying to compile libnice (v0.18 to be specific) for Android, but have run into some troubles. How can I compile libnice for Android? I have listed my attempts so far below.

**1st Attempt**

My first try was using a custom Android.mk makefile but I got an error stating `AI_NUMERICHOST undeclared` (adding `#include <netdb.h>` did not resolve this and I'm out of ideas here). See my Android.mk below

```
LOCAL_PATH  := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE        := glib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES     := lib/libglib-2.0.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE        := gobject
LOCAL_SRC_FILES     := lib/libgobject-2.0.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE        := gmodule
LOCAL_SRC_FILES     := lib/libgmodule-2.0.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE        := gio
LOCAL_SRC_FILES     := lib/libgio-2.0.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE        := gthread
LOCAL_SRC_FILES     := lib/libgthread-2.0.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE        := ffi
LOCAL_SRC_FILES     := lib/libffi.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE        := iconv
LOCAL_SRC_FILES     := lib/libiconv.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE        := intl
LOCAL_SRC_FILES     := lib/libintl.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE        := xml2
LOCAL_SRC_FILES     := lib/libxml2.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE        := z
LOCAL_SRC_FILES     := lib/libz.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)


include $(CLEAR_VARS)
NICE                := libnice-0.1.8
LOCAL_MODULE        := ice_jni
LOCAL_LDLIBS        := -llog 

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES  := glib gobject gmodule gio gthread ffi iconv intl xml2 z 

NICE_INCLUDES       := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include \
                        $(LOCAL_PATH)/lib/glib-2.0/include \
                        $(LOCAL_PATH)/lib/libffi-3.0.13/include \
                        $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/include/*) \
                        $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(NICE)/nice \
                        $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(NICE)/agent \
                        $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(NICE)/random \
                        $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(NICE)/socket \
                        $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(NICE)/stun

NICE_SRC            := $(patsubst $(LOCAL_PATH)/%, %, $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(NICE)/agent/*.c)) \
                        $(patsubst $(LOCAL_PATH)/%, %, $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(NICE)/random/*.c)) \
                        $(patsubst $(LOCAL_PATH)/%, %, $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(NICE)/socket/*.c)) \
                        $(patsubst $(LOCAL_PATH)/%, %, $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(NICE)/stun/*.c))

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES        := $(LOCAL_PATH) \
                            $(NICE_INCLUDES)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES         := ICE.cpp \
                            $(NICE_SRC)

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

The static libraries are copied over from the gstreamer 1.4.1 debug version and are selected in accordance with [the guide](http://insembedded.wordpress.com/2014/04/09/import-libnice-on-android/) mentioned below.

**2nd Attempt**

I then tried to compile a static library referring to [this guide](http://insembedded.wordpress.com/2014/04/09/import-libnice-on-android/), which is again causing trouble:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=`pwd`/../gstreamer/lib/pkgconfig  
export CFLAGS="--sysroot=`pwd`/../toolchain/sysroot"
./configure --prefix=`pwd`/../build --host=arm-linux-androideabi
```

This results in the error below. Adding `-mthumb` or `-marm` to CFLAGS yields a `C compiler cannot create executables` error during configure.

```
stunagent.c: Assembler messages:
stunagent.c:160: Error: no such instruction: `rev %eax,%eax'
stunagent.c:676: Error: no such instruction: `rev16 %ax,%ax'
```

The mentioned lines do not contain ASM but calls to `htons` and `ntohl`, so I guess I did something wrong...

I used `make_standalone_toolchain` from the NDK using various Android versions to create the toolchain.

Can anybody help? Thanks in advance!
~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FINALLY! This took me way too long. The problem was that libnice creates a `config.h` file during configure which defines some macros (`HAVE_NETDB_H` among others). Although I was not able to compile libnice with my toolchain I was able to generate a valid config.h which I could use. After this I had to make some additional adjustments to my `Android.mk`. I'll post both files below for others in search of answers.

(Note: you still need glib. As my project uses gstreamer I was able to use the shared library created by the gstreamer build script which contains glib.)

Cheers!

========================

**Android.mk**

```
LOCAL_PATH  := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
NICE                    := libnice-0.1.8
LOCAL_MODULE            := nice_jni
LOCAL_LDLIBS            := -llog 

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES  := gstreamer_android
LOCAL_CFLAGS            += -DHAVE_CONFIG_H

NICE_DIRS               := $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(NICE)/ \
                            $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(NICE)/agent/ \
                            $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(NICE)/nice/ \
                            $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(NICE)/random/ \
                            $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(NICE)/socket/ \
                            $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(NICE)/stun/ \
                            $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(NICE)/stun/usages/
#                           $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(NICE)/stun/tools/ \

NICE_INCLUDES           := $(NICE_DIRS)
NICE_SRC                := $(filter-out %test.c, $(foreach dir, $(NICE_DIRS), $(patsubst $(LOCAL_PATH)/%, %, $(wildcard $(addsuffix *.c, $(dir)))) ))

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES        := $(NICE_INCLUDES) #add your own headers if needed

LOCAL_SRC_FILES         := [YOUR_SRC_FILES] \
                            $(NICE_SRC)

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

**config.h**

(This should not differ across platforms and Android versions. I left the comments in it intentionally for future reference)

```
/* config.h.  Generated from config.h.in by configure.  */
/* config.h.in.  Generated from configure.ac by autoheader.  */

/* Define to 1 if you have the <arpa/inet.h> header file. */
#define HAVE_ARPA_INET_H 1

/* Define to 1 if C supports variable-length arrays. */
#define HAVE_C_VARARRAYS 1

/* Define to 1 if you have the <dlfcn.h> header file. */
#define HAVE_DLFCN_H 1

/* Whether getifaddrs() is available on the system */
/* #undef HAVE_GETIFADDRS */

/* Have the GUPnP IGD library */
/* #undef HAVE_GUPNP */

/* Define to 1 if you have the <ifaddrs.h> header file. */
/* #undef HAVE_IFADDRS_H */

/* Define to 1 if you have the <inttypes.h> header file. */
#define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1

/* Define to 1 if you have the <memory.h> header file. */
#define HAVE_MEMORY_H 1

/* Define to 1 if you have the <netdb.h> header file. */
#define HAVE_NETDB_H 1

/* Define to 1 if you have the <net/in.h> header file. */
/* #undef HAVE_NET_IN_H */

/* Define to 1 if you have the `poll' function. */
#define HAVE_POLL 1

/* Define to 1 if the system has the type `size_t'. */
#define HAVE_SIZE_T 1

/* Define to 1 if the system has the type `ssize_t'. */
#define HAVE_SSIZE_T 1

/* Define to 1 if stdbool.h conforms to C99. */
#define HAVE_STDBOOL_H 1

/* Define to 1 if you have the <stdint.h> header file. */
#define HAVE_STDINT_H 1

/* Define to 1 if you have the <stdlib.h> header file. */
#define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1

/* Define to 1 if you have the <strings.h> header file. */
#define HAVE_STRINGS_H 1

/* Define to 1 if you have the <string.h> header file. */
#define HAVE_STRING_H 1

/* Define to 1 if you have the <sys/stat.h> header file. */
#define HAVE_SYS_STAT_H 1

/* Define to 1 if you have the <sys/types.h> header file. */
#define HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H 1

/* Define to 1 if you have the <unistd.h> header file. */
#define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1

/* Define to 1 if the system has the type `_Bool'. */
#define HAVE__BOOL 1

/* Define to the sub-directory in which libtool stores uninstalled libraries.
   */
#define LT_OBJDIR ".libs/"

/* Define to 1 if assertions should be disabled. */
/* #undef NDEBUG */

/* Public library function implementation */
#define NICEAPI_EXPORT 

/* Name of package */
#define PACKAGE "libnice"

/* Define to the address where bug reports for this package should be sent. */
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""

/* Define to the full name of this package. */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "libnice"

/* Define to the full name and version of this package. */
#define PACKAGE_STRING "libnice 0.1.8"

/* Define to the one symbol short name of this package. */
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "libnice"

/* Define to the home page for this package. */
#define PACKAGE_URL ""

/* Define to the version of this package. */
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "0.1.8"

/* Define to 1 if you have the ANSI C header files. */
#define STDC_HEADERS 1

/* Enable extensions on AIX 3, Interix.  */
#ifndef _ALL_SOURCE
# define _ALL_SOURCE 1
#endif
/* Enable GNU extensions on systems that have them.  */
#ifndef _GNU_SOURCE
# define _GNU_SOURCE 1
#endif
/* Enable threading extensions on Solaris.  */
#ifndef _POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS
# define _POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS 1
#endif
/* Enable extensions on HP NonStop.  */
#ifndef _TANDEM_SOURCE
# define _TANDEM_SOURCE 1
#endif
/* Enable general extensions on Solaris.  */
#ifndef __EXTENSIONS__
# define __EXTENSIONS__ 1
#endif


/* Version number of package */
#define VERSION "0.1.8"

/* Define to `2' to get GNU/libc warnings. */
/* Only define if -O1 or more is enabled */
#if defined __OPTIMIZE__ && __OPTIMIZE__ > 0
# define _FORTIFY_SOURCE 2
#endif

/* Define to 1 if on MINIX. */
/* #undef _MINIX */

/* Define to 2 if the system does not provide POSIX.1 features except with
   this defined. */
/* #undef _POSIX_1_SOURCE */

/* Define to 1 if you need to in order for `stat' and other things to work. */
/* #undef _POSIX_SOURCE */

/* Needed to get declarations for msg_control and msg_controllen on Solaris */
/* #undef _XOPEN_SOURCE */

/* Needed to get declarations for msg_control and msg_controllen on Solaris */
#define __EXTENSIONS__ 1

/* Define to the equivalent of the C99 'restrict' keyword, or to
   nothing if this is not supported.  Do not define if restrict is
   supported directly.  */
#define restrict __restrict
/* Work around a bug in Sun C++: it does not support _Restrict or
   __restrict__, even though the corresponding Sun C compiler ends up with
   "#define restrict _Restrict" or "#define restrict __restrict__" in the
   previous line.  Perhaps some future version of Sun C++ will work with
   restrict; if so, hopefully it defines __RESTRICT like Sun C does.  */
#if defined __SUNPRO_CC && !defined __RESTRICT
# define _Restrict
# define __restrict__
#endif
```