# Using Libnice for Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, ice, libnice

I need to implement libnice on Android.  I'm aware of a couple of partial posts on this topic. However, with all the dependencies that libnice requires, I wasn't sure how to go about including, compiling and accessing all the libraries necessary for Android.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26531149/6257402) was only partially helpful. Anyone able to help with this?

Comment: Please clarify why that post did not answer your question. What have you already done to try building libnice? When you tried to build libnice, what problems did you encounter?